# Open url with content type text/csv in browser (at least Chrome) without downloading

Tags: csv, google-chrome, firefox, mime-types

I have the endpoint with **Content-Type: text/csv**.

There's no Content-Disposition header!

When I open this endpoint in browser it offers to download this file like if it has Content-Disposition header.

What I would like to achieve is just view the endpoint response in browser the same way it would do this for **Content-Type: text/plain**.
No downloading, no opening with default program - just viewing the response.

Is this at all possible at any browser?
I tried Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

If you can add a Content-Disposition header, setting the value to `incline` would solve this for you.

```
Content-Disposition: inline
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Chrome 119.